# concatenate grep output to an echo statement in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I am trying to output the number of directories in a given path on a SINGLE line. My desire is to output this:

> X-many directories

Currently, with my bash sript, I get this:

> X-many
>
> directories

Here's my code:

```
ARGUMENT=$1

ls -l $ARGUMENT | egrep -c '^drwx'; echo -n "directories"
```

How can I fix my output? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest

```
 echo "$(ls -l "$ARGUMENT" | egrep -c '^drwx') directories"
```

This uses the shell's feature of final newline removal for command substitution.

Answer (score 3):

Do not pipe to `ls` output and count directories as you can get wrong results if special characters have been used in file/directory names.

To count directories use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( "$ARGUMENT"/*/ )
echo "${#arr[@]} directories"
```

- `/` at the end of glob will make sure to match only directories in `"$ARGUMENT"` path.
- `shopt -s nullglob` is to make sure to return empty results if glob pattern fails (no directory in given argument).

Comment: shopt: command not found; this suffers from "all the worlds a Linux/bash system".

Comment: `shopt` not found in BASH?

Comment: Is it so hard to make this simple task work for any shell? Why the needless bashisms? I believe in teaching portability early on and avoiding solutions only working for a limited set of systems.

Comment: **needless bashisms** is for **[avoiding parsing `ls` command](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)**.

Answer (score 0):

as alternative solution

```
$ bc <<< "$(find /etc -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)-1"
116
```

another one

```
$ count=0; while read curr_line; do count=$((count+1)); done < <(ls -l ~/etc | grep ^d); echo ${count}
116
```

Would work correctly with spaces in the folder name

```
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 alex alex 4096 Jun 30 18:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 alex alex 4096 Jun 30 16:41 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 alex alex 4096 Jun 30 16:43 asdasd
drwxrwxr-x  2 alex alex 4096 Jun 30 16:43 dfgerte
drwxrwxr-x  2 alex alex 4096 Jun 30 16:43 somefoler with_space

$ count=0; while read curr_line; do count=$((count+1)); done < <(ls -l ./ | grep ^d); echo ${count}
3
```